# AWS-Console: DynamoDB scan on nested field

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nested-fields

I have below table in DynamoDB

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user": {
        "age": "26",
        "email": "testuser@gmail.com",
        "name": "test user"
    }
}
```

Using AWS console, I want to scan all the records whose email address contains **gmail.com**

I am trying this but it is giving no results.

I am new to AWS, not sure what's wrong here. Is it not possible to scan on nested fields?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been trying to figure this out myself but it would seem that nested item scans are not supported through the console.

I'm going based off of this which offer some alternative options via CLI or SDK: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=931016

Comment: You can try this tool (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.settingup.html). It has the option to add filter on nested fields. Go to "Operation builder" tab.